# How can I search through a 2D array without for loops?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I have a `Vec<Vec<char>>` and I want to find all the x,y positions of a specific character, let's say 'x'. I can use a double for loop with enumerate and manually build up the solution (and I would guess this is the sane thing to do), but is there a nice way to do it with nothing but iterators?

More or less I'm looking for ways to clean this up:

```
let locs: Vec<(usize, (usize, &char))> = grid.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(ind, row)|
          iter::repeat(ind)
            .zip(row.iter()
               .enumerate()))
    .filter(|&(x, (y, ch))| ch == 'x')
    .collect();
```

For one, is there a way to flatten the tuples?

Comment: I tried, but the more I did the less sane it looked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt, which does flatten the tuples:

```
let locs: Vec<(usize, usize, char)> = grid.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(y, row)| {
        row.iter()
           .enumerate()
           .map(move |(x, &c)| (x,y,c))
    })
    .filter(|&(_,_,c)| c == 'x')
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", locs)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=971e4e82a0fe021a3e733cefa8fd0541&version=stable&backtrace=0)

My approach was to first flatten to `(x,y,c)` and then filter.  I took the liberty of returning the actual `char`s rather than references.

The `move` closure was needed because otherwise the inner closure (which lives longer, inside the iterator, than the outer closure) had a reference to the outer `y`.

If I wanted to do this more often, I would write an `Iterator` implementation which let me do:

```
let locs: Vec<(usize, usize, char) =
    iter2d(grid)
    .filter(&|_,_,c| c == 'x')
    .collect();
```

The implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: The OP wrote a tuple with a tuple inside `(usize, (usize, &char))`. You solution work anyway? I'm learning rust, so it's a newbie comment.

Comment: The question also asked if the tuple could be flattened, i.e. removing the tuple nesting.